# How to locate public folder using PHP?

Tags: php, public-html

I am writing installation script in PHP and part of my application may be installed in the folder that is one level above the public folder. Usually, public folder is called "public_html" but that may not always be the case. Is there some easy way to locate the name or path of the root public folder using PHP?

Comment: How do you know your script will always have access to that folder, if it even exists?  In any case, just use `../`.

Comment: True about permissions, but I figure I will deal with that separately.
../ may not work when my installation script runs on a sub-domain, which often has site root like public_html/subdomain/. Using ../ will take me up to public_html, but I need to go one level up.

Answer (score 5):

Try `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php))

If you want to get the directory above it, you can use [`dirname`](http://www.php.net/dirname).

[Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9222334/x#comment11612623_9222334) does have a point, though; your script may not have access to that directory.

Comment: I think he wants the folder above the doc root.

Comment: To make sure you can write to the folder above the web root ... `$levelUp = dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); if (is_writable($levelUp)) { ... }`

Comment: When a site is on subdomain, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] gives me something like /home1/user/public_html/subdomain. And public_html can be called something else on different servers.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will provide the full path up to `public_html` and you can explode with slash "/" and get last index of the exploded array.
2. You can also use [realpath](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) with argument "../", if you don't know the actual file name. This will return you the full parent path of `public_html`.

Hope one of this two will work for you :)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know where my installation script is being ran from. It may be public_html/install.php, but it may also be from public_html/subfolder/install.php. For those two cases $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] will give me different results. And I can't look for "public_html" in either path because this directory may be called something else, like "www".